# Hash for secure file downloads?

Tags: hash

Is there any hash structure that can be used for secure download of a file and validation of its contents?

Looks like all hashes like MD5 are made for consistency check and are vulnerable to hash extension attack, so it is possible to create another file with the same MD5 by just appending to the end of it.

I am writing an automated service that downloads data over insecure channels and I want to make sure that MITM can not alter file.

**UPDATE**: Hash is transferred to the user through secure channel. Right now I am using hash + filesize combination, to avoid hash extension attacks. Is it possible to use just single hash function?

**UPDATE 2**: I misunderstood what a **length extension attack** is. Quoting @CodeInChaos:

> It does not give you a collision, it merely allows you to compute the hash of a longer file given the hash of a shorter file whose contents you don't know

So it is not possible to just append to file with existing hash to get the same hash. Doing this will mean looking for collisions in a longer file, so the question boils down to classic "how strong is the hash function". On the other hand, it is still interesting why SHA3 is not vulnerable to hash extension, but that's another topic.

Comment: This question is not clear, you seem to be confusing hashing with encryption. A hash is an irreversible mathematical transformation of data, you can't "decrypt" a hash, so you can't use it to protect confidentiality.

Comment: @GdD it is not about encryption, it is about validation of download. Hash is received over secure channel. File is not. How to validate that the file is not a forged one?

Comment: That's the point of using a hash - if the file is different in any way than the original, even by a single bit, then the hash result will be completely different.

Comment: @GdD, but it is possible to forge a file with the same MD5 contents, so MD5 is insecure.

Comment: If you are asking about collisions then yes, collisions are possible, however the source data for a collision would almost certainly be meaningless.

Comment: @GdD not sure about meaningless data. Given that I know the contents of original file, it may be easier to jump from initial state to the final state with appended contents.

Comment: You misunderstood what a length extension attack is. It does not give you a collision, it merely allows you to compute the hash of a longer file given the hash of a shorter file whose contents you don't know.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for clarification. Looks like `length extension` is not that I thought of it in the first place and I need to rely on collisions to return to initial state after making longer file.

Comment: I defeated length extension handily by making files know their lengths.

Comment: @Joshua me too, but maybe there are hashes that already embed that info?

Comment: @techtonik: Didn't work. SHA-1 embeds the length but is vulnerable to length extension.

Comment: 1) Knowing the length is useful even with ideal hashes, since otherwise the attacker can feed you unlimited amounts of data since you don't know how much data to expect. 2) The internal state of SHA-3 is twice as big as the output, which is one way to defeat length extensions. Other SHA-3 candidates chose other defenses. 3) Take a look at Tiger-Tree-Hash, which allows verification of partial file downloads, if you obtain the appropriate intermediate hashes.

Comment: 2) I wonder why hash could not just depend on byte counter as implicit state. Without knowing the counter, it is hard to continue it. 3) TTH looks promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern hashes like SHA-256 provide a strong protection against hash collision attacks, that is it is practically impossible to create a different program which has the same hash as the original program - no matter if the size is the same or differs.

This still leaves the possibility that the attacker not only modifies the file but also the accompanying hash, which means you have to find a way to transfer the hash in a secure way to the user.

Comment: Hashes are transferred securely. Modified the question to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this, and your attack scenario is very unlikely to happen.

First, if you are using a secure channel to send the hash (I imagine you are using SSL/TLS), you should use the same channel to send the file. TLS is very secure if rightly implemented, it's a *fire and forget* solution, and the administrative overhead is pretty negligible after implementation. It's a little more expensive than plain HTTP, but the benefits more than compensate.

Second, if an attacker is able to intercept the transmission, taint the downloaded file, and redirect the changed file to your client, nothing will stop him from doing the same to the hash. We can say that the file will very likely be bigger than the hash. Intercepting a hash would be trivial.

Third, if the attacker have enough resources to intercept the transmission, download the original file, create a collision on a SHA-256 hash and send the changed file, he will have enough resources to ask you to send the changed file to the receiver with a correct hash and don't tell the receiver. And that would be easier to the attacker, and you don't have any protection against.

Don't worry about intercepted and changed file downloads. Worry about error in transmission. Even a CRC32 is enough to verify a download. If this transmission occurs over HTTP(s), you can use a custom header:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SuperHTTPServer/20.1
Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:23:45 GMT
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 12345
X-MD5-Hash: cc0c8d81fc54e0bd077a5678eaadf2ff
```

The custom client will have to read the reader, get the hash, and calculate the result. You can send both the file and the hash using only one transaction.

By the way, the [Hash Length Extension Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) is not what you think. As CodesIsChaos said, the attack consists on getting a hash and a partial string, adding something to it, and recalculating the hash even without knowing the original string. And while is possible to create a collision with MD5, is not trivial, and certainly not practical to create on-fly during a file transmission.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about Hash Length Extension. Wikipedia holds a very bad article about that with all that maths notation. This is not a question about real-time attack, but about prepared, so if MD5 collision is possible to get in a week or a year, then MD5 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 and SHA256 are both hashing functions that are commonly used to compute the checksum of a file for verification purposes.  An MD5 checksum is 128 bits long, whereas a SHA256 checksum is 256 bits long, so an attacker would be less likely to find a collision if you use SHA256.

Another thing you can do to provide a way for your users to verify the authenticity of your file is to digitally sign the file.  Of course, this requires that you distribute your public signing key in such a way that your users could verify its authenticity.

Comment: No, I need to give users a hash and then make sure that he will be able to locate and download the right file using the hash alone. Is that possible? With protection from quantum computers etc.

Comment: @techtonik That sounds like what BitTorrent Magnet links are doing.

Comment: @Philipp exactly. How secure are they?

Comment: You sort of make it sound like finding a collision on sha128 would be easy. Right now that's not the case.

Comment: No, finding an input file that produces a hash collision on a SHA128 hash would not be easy - especially when the input file also needs to be executable and must perform some particular operation.  Notwithstanding, it's harder to find collisions when longer hash functions are used.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It wouldn't be super easy, but it's clearly feasible for a determined attacker. The work for finding a collision in an unbroken 128 bit hash is 2^64. That's about a minute of work for the bitcoin mining network.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, isn't the computing power of the Bitcoin mining network considered to be rather difficult to reproduce? My recollection is that the security of Bitcoin is based on that fact.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It shows that a collision should cost <1000$ once you've amortized the R&D effort of building a custom chip for it.

Comment: I don't follow that logic @CodesInChaos. I'm not necessarily saying that you're wrong, just that I don't see it.

Comment: The whole bitcoin network currently earns 25*330$+fees every 10 mins. Since miners probably wouldn't operate at a loss, that means that a the work the network performs each minute shouldn't be worth more 1000$ or so. (It's a bit more complicated due to the varying bitcoin value, but should be a decent estimation)

Comment: @CodesInChaos (+NeilS) There is no SHA128; SHA1 is 160 bits, MD5 128 -- and broken for collision by non bruteforce. Bitcoin is currently about 2^56/s SHA256; assuming a 128-bit hash is about the same 2^64 is 4 minutes (not a big difference, and going down steadily). But for brute collision you also need storage, and 2^64 input blocks (plus a little overhead) is probably $30billion, all spent before the first result, unless you trade storage against substantially more computation which also increases your cost. Plus, to replace an existing file collision isn't enough.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I know that there is no SHA-128. I was talking about an unbroken 128 bit hash, such as SHA-256 truncated to 128 bits. You only need negligible amounts of storage to find collisions (using cycle finding and/or distinguished points), the cost is dominated by computing about 2^64 hash invocations, which is pretty cheap if you disregard the effort of developing custom hardware for the problem.